# Create input elements in Javascript - Required

Tags: javascript, forms

I made a JS script which displays some inputs when a precise option is selected.

The script seems to work.
When I select the "5" and "7" options, the "license expiration" and the "end of services year" fields mustn't be required. In other case, they must.
The only issue is that when I select an option which puts these two fields in the required state, they stay in this state when I change the option for a non-required state.

But if I select directly these options, there is no issue.
So the issue is during the required to non-required state transition.

Can you please help me to resolve this issue ?

Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<form id="addCustomerForm" onSubmit="handleFormSubmitAddCustomer(this)">

      <label for="customer">Customer *</label><br/>
      <input type="text" id="customer" name="customer" placeholder="Required" required><br/><br/>

      <label for="contractScope">Contract Scope *</label><br/>
      <select name="contractScope" id="contractScope" onChange="moreLicensesOption(this)" required>
        <option disabled selected value style="display:none"> Required </option>
        <option value="1"> 1</option><br/>
        <option value="2"> 2</option><br/>
        <option value="3"> 3</option><br/>
        <option value="4"> 4</option><br/>
        <option value="5"> 5 </option><br/>
        <option value="6"> 6 </option><br/>
        <option value="7"> 7 </option><br/>
        <option value="8"> 8</option><br/>
        <option value="9"> 9</option><br/>
        <option value="10"> 10</option><br/>
        <option value="11"> 11</option><br/>
        <option value="12"> 12</option><br/>
        <option value="13"> 13</option>
      </select><br/><br/>
    
      <label for="aType">A Type *</label><br/>
      <select multiple id="aType" name="aType" required>
        <option value="A1"> A1 </option><br/>
        <option value="A2"> A2 </option><br/>
        <option value="A3"> A3 </option><br/>
        <option value="A4"> A4 </option><br/>
        <option value="A5"> A5 </option><br/>
        <option value="A6"> A6 </option><br/>
      </select><br/><br/>

      <label for="classrooms">Classrooms</label><br/>
      <input type="text" id="classrooms" name="classrooms"><br/><br/>

      <div id="divNumberLicenses"></div>

      <div id="divNumberDongle"></div>

      <div id="divNumberL"></div>

      <div id="divLicenseExpiration"></div>

      <div id="divEndOfServicesYear"></div>

      <label for="comment">Comment</label><br/>
      <input type="text" id="comment" name="comment"><br/><br/>

      <label for="contact">Contact *</label><br/>
      <input type="text" id="contact" name="contact" placeholder="Required" required><br/><br/>

      <label for="phone">Phone *</label><br/>
      <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Required" required><br/><br/>

      <label for="mail">Mail *</label><br/>
      <input type="text" id="mail" name="mail" placeholder="Required" required><br/><br/>

      <label for="address">Address *</label><br/>
      <input type="text" id="address" name="address" placeholder="Required" required><br/><br/>

      <label for="aContact">A Contact *</label><br/>
      <input type="text" id="aContact" name="aContact" placeholder="Required" required><br/><br/>

      <label for="deploymentPriority">Deployment Priority</label><br/>
      <input type="text" id="deploymentPriority" name="deploymentPriority"><br/><br/>

      <label for="initialDeploymentDate"> Initial Deployment Date </label><br/>
      <input type="date" id="initialDeploymentDate" name="initialDeploymentDate"><br/><br/>

      <label for="multiA">MultiA</label><br/>
      <input type="text" id="multiA" name="multiA"><br/><br/>

      <label for="path">Path</label><br/>
      <input type="text" id="path" name="path"></br><br/>

      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
<!-- JavaScriptAddCustomer.html -->

<script>

  // Defines the <br/> in the form
  var br = document.createElement("br");

  // Defines the number of licenses label and input
  var licensesLabel = document.createElement("label");
  var licenses = document.createElement("input");
  licenses.type = "number";licenses.min = "0";
  licenses.id = "licenses";licenses.name = "licenses";
  licenses.value = "";

  // Defines number of dongle keys label and input
  var dongleKeysLabel = document.createElement("label");
  dongleKeysLabel.innerHTML = "No. of dongle keys *";
  var dongleKeys = document.createElement("input");
  dongleKeys.type = "number"; dongleKeys.min = "0";
  dongleKeys.id = "dongleKeys"; dongleKeys.name = "dongleKeys";
  dongleKeys.value = ""; dongleKeys.placeholder = "Required - Numerical";
  dongleKeys.required = true;

  // Defines the Secure L label and input
  var secureLLabel = document.createElement("label");
  secureLLabel.innerHTML = "No. of secure L keys *";
  var secureL = document.createElement("input");
  secureL.type = "number"; secureL.min = "0";
  secureL.id = "secureL"; secureL.name = "secureL";
  secureL.value = ""; secureL.placeholder = "Required - Numerical";
  secureL.required = true;

  // Defines the end of services year label and input
  var licenseExpirationLabel = document.createElement("label");
  var licenseExpiration = document.createElement("input");
  licenseExpiration.type = "date";
  licenseExpiration.id = "licenseExpiration"; licenseExpiration.name = "licenseExpiration";

  // Defines the end of services year label and input
  var endOfServicesYearLabel = document.createElement("label");
  var endOfServicesYear = document.createElement("input");
  endOfServicesYear.type = "number"; endOfServicesYear.min = "0";
  endOfServicesYear.id = "endOfServicesYear"; endOfServicesYear.name = "endOfServicesYear";
  endOfServicesYear.value = "";

  /**
   * Makes appear inputs in function of selected options
   * @param optionSelected The option selected in the dropdown
   */
  function moreLicensesOption(optionSelected) {

    // Defines the area where created elements will be
    var divNumberLicensesNode = document.getElementById('divNumberLicenses');
    var divNumberDongleNode = document.getElementById('divNumberDongle');
    var divNumberLNode = document.getElementById('divNumberL');
    var divLicenseExpirationNode = document.getElementById('divLicenseExpiration');
    var divEndOfServicesYearNode = document.getElementById('divEndOfServicesYear');

    // Number of licenses input not required
    if (optionSelected.value == "5" || optionSelected.value == "7") {

      /* Deletes previous inputs */
      while (divNumberLicensesNode.hasChildNodes()) {
        divNumberLicensesNode.removeChild(divNumberLicensesNode.lastChild);
      }

      licensesLabel.innerHTML = "No. of licenses";
      licenses.placeholder = "Numerical";
      licenses.required = false;

      divNumberLicensesNode.append(licensesLabel); divNumberLicensesNode.append(br.cloneNode());
      divNumberLicensesNode.append(licenses); divNumberLicensesNode.append(br.cloneNode());
      divNumberLicensesNode.append(br.cloneNode());

    // Number of licenses input required
    } else {

      while (divNumberLicensesNode.hasChildNodes()) {
        divNumberLicensesNode.removeChild(divNumberLicensesNode.lastChild);
      }

      licensesLabel.innerHTML = "No. of licenses *";
      licenses.placeholder = "Required - Numerical";
      licenses.required = true;

      divNumberLicensesNode.append(licensesLabel); divNumberLicensesNode.append(br.cloneNode());
      divNumberLicensesNode.append(licenses); divNumberLicensesNode.append(br.cloneNode());
      divNumberLicensesNode.append(br.cloneNode());
    }

    // Number of dongle keys input required
    if (optionSelected.value == "2" || optionSelected.value == "3") {

      while (divNumberDongleNode.hasChildNodes()) {
        divNumberDongleNode.removeChild(divNumberDongleNode.lastChild);
      }

      divNumberDongleNode.append(dongleKeysLabel); divNumberDongleNode.append(br.cloneNode());
      divNumberDongleNode.append(dongleKeys); divNumberDongleNode.append(br.cloneNode());
      divNumberDongleNode.append(br.cloneNode());
    } else {
      while (divNumberDongleNode.hasChildNodes()) {
        divNumberDongleNode.removeChild(divNumberDongleNode.lastChild);
      }
    }

    if (optionSelected.value == "2" || optionSelected.value == "3"
        || optionSelected.value == "9" || optionSelected.value == "4"
        || optionSelected.value == "8" || optionSelected.value == "10"
        || optionSelected.value == "11" || optionSelected.value == "12") {

      while (divNumberLNode.hasChildNodes()) {
        divNumberLNode.removeChild(divNumberLNode.lastChild);
      }

      divNumberLNode.append(secureLLabel); divNumberLNode.append(br.cloneNode());
      divNumberLNode.append(secureL); divNumberLNode.append(br.cloneNode());
      divNumberLNode.append(br.cloneNode());
    } else {
      while (divNumberLNode.hasChildNodes()) {
        divNumberLNode.removeChild(divNumberLNode.lastChild);
      }
    }

    // License expiration date input not required
    if (optionSelected.value == "5" || optionSelected.value == "7") { // ISSUE HERE

      while (divNumberLicenseExpirationNode.hasChildNodes()) {
        divLicenseExpirationNode.removeChild(divLicenseExpirationNode.lastChild);
      }

      licenseExpirationLabel.innerHTML = "License Expiration";
      licenseExpiration.required = false;

      divLicenseExpirationNode.append(licenseExpirationLabel); divLicenseExpirationNode.append(br.cloneNode());
      divLicenseExpirationNode.append(licenseExpiration); divLicenseExpirationNode.append(br.cloneNode());
      divLicenseExpirationNode.append(br.cloneNode());

    // Number of licenses input required
    } else {

      while (divLicenseExpirationNode.hasChildNodes()) {
        divLicenseExpirationNode.removeChild(divLicenseExpirationNode.lastChild);
      }

      licenseExpirationLabel.innerHTML = "License Expiration *";
      licenseExpiration.required = true;

      divLicenseExpirationNode.append(licenseExpirationLabel); divLicenseExpirationNode.append(br.cloneNode());
      divLicenseExpirationNode.append(licenseExpiration); divLicenseExpirationNode.append(br.cloneNode());
      divLicenseExpirationNode.append(br.cloneNode());
    }

    // End of services year input not required
    if (optionSelected.value == "5" || optionSelected.value == "6"
        || optionSelected.value == "7") { // SAME ISSUE HERE

      while (divEndOfServicesYearNode.hasChildNodes()) {
        divEndOfServicesYearNode.removeChild(divEndOfServicesYearNode.lastChild);
      }

      endOfServicesYearLabel.innerHTML = "End of services year";
      endOfServicesYear.placeholder = "Numerical";
      endOfServicesYear.required = false;

      divEndOfServicesYearNode.append(endOfServicesYearLabel); divEndOfServicesYearNode.append(br.cloneNode());
      divEndOfServicesYearNode.append(endOfServicesYear); divEndOfServicesYearNode.append(br.cloneNode());
      divEndOfServicesYearNode.append(br.cloneNode());

    // Number of licenses input required
    } else {

      while (divEndOfServicesYearNode.hasChildNodes()) {
        divEndOfServicesYearNode.removeChild(divEndOfServicesYearNode.lastChild);
      }

      endOfServicesYearLabel.innerHTML = "End of services year *";
      endOfServicesYear.placeholder = "Required - Numerical";
      endOfServicesYear.required = true;

      divEndOfServicesYearNode.append(endOfServicesYearLabel); divEndOfServicesYearNode.append(br.cloneNode());
      divEndOfServicesYearNode.append(endOfServicesYear); divEndOfServicesYearNode.append(br.cloneNode());
      divEndOfServicesYearNode.append(br.cloneNode());
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Please replace the current code in the question by a [mcve].

Comment: And ideally, as [runnable snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right. I should have optimize my code.
I resolved the issue by minimizing the code with these two functions.
Don't know what appends but my issue is gone.

Thanks!

```
function addInput(node, label, input) {
    node.append(label); node.append(br.cloneNode());
    node.append(input); node.append(br.cloneNode());
    node.append(br.cloneNode());
}


function deleteNodeContent(node) {
  while (node.hasChildNodes()) {
    node.removeChild(node.lastChild);
  }
}
```